# Hook to get image after being loaded from a layout

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-drawable

Is there any way to get an image being pointed by an android layout and modify it before it is receceived by the requester?

For example if I have an image view like:

```
<ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/myimage.png"
         />
```

Is it possible to register to any hook (or any other way) where I could modify the image before the ImageView receives it?.

Trying to clarify a bit more the question:

1) The ussual way android works:

- The app runs, and reads a layout with an imageview requesting @drawable/myimage.png
- The image is loaded and provided to the imageview to show it

2) What I would like to try or accomplish:

- The app runs, and reads a layout with an imageview requesting @drawable/myimage.png
- I previously, somehow, told android to send me the image/stream before
  providing it to the imageview. I modify it
- I return the modified image and it is shown in the imageview.

Do anybody know if this is possilbe? I have seen offuscators like dexguard that can do this. Any tip would be really helpful because I haven't found any way to do it after some days of investigation.

Cheers.

Comment: try using picasso or glide library.. they allow modification on your image view..

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer to my question. Picasso or Glide are libs to stream images to a image view from local or remote (don't know if it has other functionality), but they don't allow to do what I'm asking to do. They both will show on the imageview the original image.

Answer (score 0):

- You will need to extract bitmap from resources
- Modify the bitmap
- Apply modified bitmap to imageview through java code

These snippets might help

```
//extract bitmap from drawable resources    
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.icon_resource);
//modify bitmap code here

//apply modified bitmap to image view    
imageview.setBitmap(icon);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but, again, this does not solve what I want to do. This code simply loads the image on its own and feeds the imageview manually. I want to "catch" the request of an image from a view in a layout and get in the middle and provide the output to that imageview. I'm doing this in an app I am doing as a proof of concept. I know how to do it the ussual way (the way you did).

Comment: I think you might need to create a new class extending ImageView, find the function which requests the image and shows it in the image and modifies there. I am not sure which function will be suitable for that but observing the activity of each function by overriding them and using logs might work.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks again @kamran but I'm searching for a way to do it without modifying the standard imageview view. I will upvote  this answer anyway because can be of help to others. It seems offuscators like dexguard can do it, so, this is why I'm looking for this.